# Api vk получить список видеозаписей из группы в ВК?

Tags: vkontakte-api

Если вкратце то пользователь заходит на сайт и ему необходимо отдать все видеозаписи из группы в ВК. Возможно ли так сделать и какие методы для этого использовать. 
Метод video.get как я понял предоставляет доступ к видеозаписям пользователей, а не самой группы.

Answer (score 0):

Получить видеозаписи группы можно отправив **отрицательный** id.

```
owner_id= - id
```

[Подробнее](https://vk.com/dev.php?method=video.get)